# Are women halachically obligated to fast on the minor fasts?

Tags: women, fast-days

A friend of mine has told me they are not halachically obligated and yet I can not see any mention of this in the Shulchan Aruch. Please show מקורות.

Answer (score 0):

Categorically there was no exemption for "women."

There were exemptions for "pregnant, nursing, and shortly-after-birth." It seems in some communities women were in one of these categories so often that people just gathered that they were exempt altogether.