# Are women required to keep the Fast of Esther?

Tags: halacha, women, purim, fast-days, esther--the-woman

I had learned that women are only required to fast on Yom Kippur and Tisha B'Av.* But sometimes, women are obligated in mitzvos that they wouldn't ordinarily be expected (such as the time-bound mitzvos of Purim) because of the mitzvah's historical connection with women. Is the Fast of Esther an example of such a thing? What is the extent of women's obligation to fast on this day?

*Edited to note: This really isn't correct.

Comment: related but not specific to Taanis Esther - http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/63949/why-dont-israeli-women-fast

Comment: SAH you should know, what you learned is decidedly non-standard http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/64201/759

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/63949/why-dont-israeli-women-fast

Comment: I learned in a sefer (probably Ellinson's Women and Mitzvot vol. 1, but not positive) that the Fast of Esther is slightly less incumbent upon everyone /including women/ than the other fasts

Comment: @DoubleAA You're absolutely right, as I now know. Have been meaning to correct this question for awhile

Comment: Pregnant and nursing women aren't obligated in minor fasts, and many rabbis extended that to 2--3 years after childbirth even if not nursing. It therefore follows that many women weren't doing minor fasts for most of their childbearing years (which started very early, and few women lived past them; and those that did often weren't healthy enough to fast.) So it's easy to see how someone then misunderstood that as a blanket "women don't have to fast."

Comment: @Shalom Seemingly women are obligated in minor fasts before gestational day 40. Only after day 54 is it clear that they are not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=516) website, a woman is required to fast unless she doesn't feel well enough to do so

> Many authorities, including the Kaf Ha’haim (based on the Bah), the Elya Rabba, the Kisur Shulhan Aruch, Hacham Bension Abba Shaul, Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach and Rabbi Mazuz, ruled that the status of a woman during this period vis-à-vis Ta’anit Ester depends solely on her physical condition.  If she says that she feels well and capable of fasting, then, according to the accepted position, she is required to observe the fast.

Comment: It seems that website is not going accd to the practice mentioned in the question that women don't fast except on 9Av/YK, so I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: The title asks about a woman's obligation to Fast on the Taanit, and the question asks "What is the extent of women's obligation to fast on this day?" Are these not answered? If the answer has to be from within the context of what the asker has learned, then the answer is self apparent -- the asker learned that women don't have to fast. If another question is being asked, the question should be edited to clarify the need for different information.

Comment: Way to take things out of context... The relevant question is "Is the Fast of Esther an example of such a thing?" even if the other parts, taken out of context, aren't as limited. I don't need to tell you that just answering the title is a poor way of answering what the OP meant to ask. The question isn't just what did she learn; it's "in the context of the opinions that women aren't [as] obligated in minor fasts, is Taanit Esther more obligatory because of the connection to women [a la Af Hen Hayu...]?" Telling us that some think women are obligated in all fasts isn't helpful in the slightest

Comment: Which is why I also answered the final question "What is the extent of women's obligation to fast on this day?" If you can rewrite the question to explain what the "such a thing" is which would contravene the explicit learning the asker states, that would help frame a different answer.

Comment: Again, answering just the final statement of a post is a [probably slightly less, but roughly equally] poor way of answering what they are trying to ask. The key, unsurprisingly, is to read the whole post. The OP did bother to write it all, seemingly for a reason.

Comment: I guess next time, I will have to read the entire question and intuit which components are the essence of what is being asked, and then ignore the rest. Thank you for the object lesson.

Comment: That's usually a good plan. A good question will generally have no "rest" to ignore, though. Here, as you can see, your answer ignores most of the post which is a good indication that it's missing the point.

Comment: True -- I look forward to reading your answer which addresses the point of the question.

Comment: I never claimed to have an answer nor do I at this point plan to post one. Hopefully someone will.

Answer (score 1):

Rabeinu, Without getting a little Meshuge, the answer really is in the fact that Esther fasted for 3 days before she went in to see the King. Remember this was no little undertaking. Whether she was married to Mordecai or had been a virgin or had been summoned or not by the King is immaterial because in this particular case, the King was the ruler of all Persia (127 countries more or less). There's no question that Esther put her life on the line and for this she exemplifies a woman of courage and today women (moreso) than men should fast on this fast day. For some it may be hard to digest, but in my personal opinion this is a woman's fast not a man's and women in this particular case must take Ester's example of Courage by fasting.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. MY is putting significant emphasis on sources since we don't really know you. If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.